# Swift's equatable protocol conformance check

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to extend Swift's `Array` class with the following func:

```
func containsObjectIdenticalTo(obj: T) -> Bool {
    // objectPassingTest returns the first object passing the test
    return objectPassingTest { x in x == obj }
}
```

Apparently, this won't compile as the compiler doesn't know yet if `==` is implemented for type `T`. I then change the code to this

```
func containsObjectIdenticalTo(obj: T) -> Bool {
    return objectPassingTest {
        x in
        assert(x is Equatable && obj is Equatable)
        return (x as Equatable) == (obj as Equatable)
    } != nil
}
```

Which doesn't work either, since conformance against `Equatable` can't be checked (because `Equatable` wasn't defined with `@obj`) **!**

Any thoughts on this? Would be nice if there's some way to assert directly if `T` conforms to `Equatable`, but I haven't read that anywhere. Swift seems to be less dynamic than Obj-C in these stuffs.

**UPDATE:**
Tried this suggestion and it doesn't work (don't know exactly what `<T: Equatable>` is for, tho it does compile).

```
func containsObjectIdenticalTo<T: Equatable>(obj: T) -> Bool {
    var x = self[0]
    var y = self[0]
    return x == y // Error here
}
```

Comment: This looks weird. Are you writing generic code and didn't post all of it, or is T a type that is defined somewhere?

Comment: `T` is a typealias, defined in `Array` struct. Look at Swift declaration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify that T must be equatable in the Method's signature:

```
func containsObjectIdenticalTo<T: Equatable>(obj: T) -> Bool {/*...*/}
```

Comment: It looks nice, but doesn't work. Please see my updates.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen That's because you make sure the parameter is equatable but the elements in the array may not be. This answer should solve your overall problem though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24091318/754604

Answer (score 2):

i got this from ExSwift : https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift

```
 func contains <T: Equatable> (items: T...) -> Bool {
        return items.all { self.indexOf($0) >= 0 }
    }

func indexOf <U: Equatable> (item: U) -> Int? {
        if item is Element {
            if let found = find(reinterpretCast(self) as Array<U>, item) {
                return found
            }

            return nil
        }

        return nil
    }

func all (call: (Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        for item in self {
            if !call(item) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }
```

maybe you can try it

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
func containsObjectIdenticalTo<T : Equatable>(obj: T) -> Bool {
 ... etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I resorted to this solution

```
func containsObjectIdenticalTo<U: Equatable>(obj: U) -> Bool {
    return objectPassingTest({
        x in
        return x as U == obj
    }) != nil
}
```

Might not be the best (ie **safest**) one. But it works great.