# Swift dictionary get key for value

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm using a swift dictionary of type [UIImage:UIImage], and I'm trying to find a specific key for a given value.  In Objective-C I could use allKeysForValue, but there appears to be no such method for a Swift dictionary.  What should I be using?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

#### Swift 3: a more performant approach for the special case of bijective dictionaries

If the reverse dictionary lookup use case covers a bijective dictionary with a one to one relationship between keys and values, an alternative approach to the collection-exhaustive `filter` operation would be using a quicker short-circuiting approach to find *some* key, if it exists.

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func someKey(forValue val: Value) -> Key? {
        return first(where: { $1 == val })?.key
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let dict: [Int: String] = [1: "one", 2: "two", 4: "four"]

if let key = dict.someKey(forValue: "two") { 
    print(key)
} // 2
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 68):

There is, as far as I know, no built-in Swift function to get all dictionary keys
for a given value. Here is a possible implementation:

```
func allKeysForValue<K, V : Equatable>(dict: [K : V], val: V) -> [K] {
    return map(filter(dict) { $1 == val }) { $0.0 }
}
```

The `filter` reduces all key-value pairs to those with the given value.
The `map` maps the (filtered) key-value pairs to the keys alone.

Example usage:

```
let dict = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1, "d" : 2]
let keys = allKeysForValue(dict, 1)
println(keys) // [a, c]
```

**Update for Swift 2:** As of Xcode 7 beta 2, this can now be achieved
with an extension method for dictionaries of equatable values
(thanks to [Airspeed Velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3925941/airspeed-velocity) to make me aware of this in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value?lq=1#comment50372674_30724543)):

```
extension Dictionary where Value : Equatable {
    func allKeysForValue(val : Value) -> [Key] {
        return self.filter { $1 == val }.map { $0.0 }
    }
}

let dict = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1, "d" : 2]
let keys = dict.allKeysForValue(1)
print(keys) // [a, c]
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func allKeys(forValue val: Value) -> [Key] {
        return self.filter { $1 == val }.map { $0.0 }
    }
}

let dict = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1, "d" : 2]
let keys = dict.allKeys(forValue: 1)
print(keys) // [a, c]
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the value as a string rather than as an array? In my setup there will always only be a single unique value for every key (it is a japanese to romanji dictionary).

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that I've been using this approach in my project for a while, and noticed today while profiling that it can be *very* slow... looking for an alternative.

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi: Thank you for the edit. However, I decided to revert to the previous version because I think that `allKeys(forValue:)` is correct even in Swift 3. Existing methods with similar naming are `index(forKey:)`, `update(value: forKey)`, `value(forKey:)`.

Answer (score 46):

Understand that most of these answers get the dictionary's entire set of keys before searching through it. This answer uses the `first(where:)` method which returns after the key is found.

**Swift 5 (inline)**

```
if let key = someDictionary.first(where: { $0.value == someValue })?.key {
    // use key
}
```

**Swift 5 (extension)**

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func key(from value: Value) -> Key? {
        return self.first(where: { $0.value == value })?.key
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let key = someDictionary.key(from: someValue)) // optional

if let key = someDictionary.key(from: someValue) {
    // non-optional
}
```

Comment: That's AWESOME! This should be the current correct answer.

Comment: @Adrian note that this answer uses exactly the same approach as the **accepted** answer, which was posted 3 years before this one. This answer fails to mention, however, that one should use this with care, explicitly knowing that it will yield _some_ key, particularly in dictionaries where several keys stores the same value.

Answer (score 44):

You can use `allKeys(for:)` if you cast to `NSDictionary`:

```
let keys = (dict as NSDictionary).allKeys(for: image) as! [UIImage]
```

Comment: Thanks that works nicely, and is a nice clean solution.

Comment: Just a tiny addition, I used this code as a pattern to extract a Int key from a dictionary: 

`let keys = (ItemDict as NSDictionary).allKeysForObject(orderItems[indexPath.row])`

Then you can access like:

`let someIntValue = keys[0].integerValue;`

Works like a dream, thanks!

Comment: Swift 3: `let keys = (dict as NSDictionary).allKeys(for: image) as! [UIImage]`

Answer (score 15):

```
let dict = ["key1":2,"key2":6,"key3":8,"key4":8]
let searchingValue = 8
let b = dict.filter {$0.value == searchingValue}
let a = b.keys.first
```

*`b`* provides map with *`searchingValue`* which is  `["key4":8,"key3":8]`

*`b.keys.first`* provides first element of the all filtered keys which is *`g`*

*`a`* is the rquired key for value *`8`*

Comment: Add some explanation about your answer

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach, which I wrote about [on my blog](https://ijoshsmith.com/2016/04/14/find-keys-by-value-in-swift-dictionary/). It was tested against Swift 2.2.

````
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
  /// Returns all keys mapped to the specified value.
  /// ```
  /// let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3]
  /// let keys = dict.keysForValue(2)
  /// assert(keys == ["B"])
  /// assert(dict["B"] == 2)
  /// ```
  func keysForValue(value: Value) -> [Key] {
    return flatMap { (key: Key, val: Value) -> Key? in
      value == val ? key : nil
    }
  } 
}
````

It's the most efficient implementation posted to this thread that yields all keys mapped to a specified value, because it uses `flatMap`, instead of `filter` and then `map`. I wrote about `flatMap` in my [Higher-order functions in Swift](https://ijoshsmith.com/2015/12/09/higher-order-functions-in-swift/) article, if you're interested.

Also, because my method is generic (by virtue of being in the `Dictionary<Key,Value>` generic class) you don't need to cast its result to the key's type, which is necessary when using `allKeysForObject(_:)` from `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you for this, I found it to be a very clean way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 5):

The Swift 2 version:

```
func allKeysForValue<K, V : Equatable>(dict: [K : V], val: V) -> [K] {
    return dict.filter{ $0.1 == val }.map{ $0.0 }
}
```

Comment: Why it is `$0.1` and `$0.0` instead of `$0` and `$1` please?

Comment: Because you are mapping over a dictionary, $0 is a dictionary element. $0.0 is the key and $0.1 is the value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get your point. You said *$0 is a dictionary element*, but `key` and `value` are dictionary elements, right? Because `dictionary = [key:valule]`.

Comment: Do you mean `$0` is the first element in dictionary? Like `[firstKey:firstValue]`?

Comment: In Swift Dictionaries are implemented as generic collections. The contents of a collection are accessed by iterating over its elements. In the case of a Dictionary these elements are defined as a tuples of key, value pairs. You can access the individual parts of a tuple using an index, so $0.0 corresponds to the first (a key) and $0.1 to the second (the value related to the key).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to find *some* key for a value (i.e. not *all* of them if there is more than one, but just any arbitrary one):

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {

    func someKeyFor(value: Value) -> Key? {

        guard let index = indexOf({ $0.1 == value }) else {
            return nil
        }

        return self[index].0

    }

}
```

Above returns `nil` if there is no such key for a value.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in case you need any key for a specific value. In my case was the easiest approach. Hope that it helps:

#### Swift 4.1+

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value: Equatable {
    func key(for value: Value) -> Key? {
        return compactMap { value == $1 ? $0 : nil }.first
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know that the values are unique, this is an option:

```swift
public extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
  /// The only key that maps to `value`.
  /// - Throws: `OnlyMatchError`
  func onlyKey(for value: Value) throws -> Key {
    try onlyMatch { $0.value == value } .key
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The only match for a predicate.
  /// - Throws: `OnlyMatchError`
  func onlyMatch(for getIsMatch: (Element) throws -> Bool) throws -> Element {
    guard let onlyMatch: Element = (
      try reduce(into: nil) { onlyMatch, element in
        switch ( onlyMatch, try getIsMatch(element) ) {
        case (_, false):
          break
        case (nil, true):
          onlyMatch = element
        case (.some, true):
          throw onlyMatchError.moreThanOneMatch
        }
      }
    ) else { throw onlyMatchError.noMatches }

    return onlyMatch
  }
}

/// An error thrown from a call to `onlyMatch`.
public enum OnlyMatchError: Error {
  case noMatches
  case moreThanOneMatch
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(
  try ["skunky": "monkey", "": ""].onlyKey(for: ""),
  ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter through the dictionary and find the value that matches the value you're looking for and then get all the keys that are paired with that value in the dictionary.

FYI: `someValue` in this answer represents the hypothetical value you're looking for

```
dictionary.filter{$0.value == someValue}.keys
```