# Count item in array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, count

I want to know who have "choix1" in this array.

`var arrayVote = ["James: choix1, Julien: choix2, Paul: choix1, Teddy; choix1"]`

And i want for result: An array with the name of personnes who have "choix1"

Like that : `[James, Paul, Teddy]`

Comment: Are you sure this is an Array and not a Dictionary? Alternatively, are you sure this isn't an Array containing one element, `"James: choix1, Julien: choix2, Paul: choix1, Teddy; choix1"`? By "are you sure" I mean "have you accidentally miscopied code".

Comment: Use dictionary in this case is much easier.

Comment: If you actually meant  a *dictionary* then you'll find solutions here: [Swift dictionary get key for value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218669/swift-dictionary-get-key-for-value).

Comment: No i mean Array, my data is already with this Type

Comment: Then you'll have to dissect the string first. That's possible, but cumbersome: what if a *person* has a comma, colon, or "choice" in its name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create `[NSDictionary]` instead on `[String]` and do like so:

```
var arrayVote = ["James": "choix1", "Julien": "choix2", "Paul": "choix1", "Teddy": "choix1"]
var result: [String] = []
arrayVote.forEach {
    if $1 == "choix1" {
        result.append($0)
    }
}
print(result) // ["Paul", "Teddy", "James"]
```

Comment: All my code is with that, You really don't know with Array ?

Comment: Just want to give you an easier solution. You really want to do with the difficult way?