# Reverse Swift dictionary lookup

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
let ints: [Int: String] = [
    0: "0",
    1: "1",
    2: "2",
    3: "3",
    4: "4",
    5: "5",
    6: "6",
    7: "7",
    8: "8",
    9: "9",
    10: "A",
    11: "B",
    // etc...
]
```

I can look up an integer with `ints[5]` to get `"5"`. How can I look up the integer from the string? I want to do something like `ints.keys["5"]` -> `5`.

At the moment, I have just written the dictionary backwards:

```
let chars: [String: Int] = [
    "0": 0,
    "1": 1,
    "2": 2,
    "3": 3,
    "4": 4,
    "5": 5,
    "6": 6,
    "7": 7,
    "8": 8,
    "9": 9,
    "A": 10,
    "B": 11,
    // etc...
]
```

I can do `chars["5"]` to get `5`, but this is a cumbersome solution since my dictionary is big and want to be able to change it easily if needed.

### Clarification

I don't want to programmatically construct the dictionaries, but just keep one hard coded.

Comment: is there any reason to write them down by hand at all?? The mapping looks pretty basic.

Comment: I wrote it down basic to make the question easier to explain.

Comment: well, you made it too basic. Is the mapping even invertible? Is it always a 1:1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift dictionary get key for value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218669/swift-dictionary-get-key-for-value). – But if you do *many* lookups for the *same* dictionary then I would suggest to create a dictionary with the inverse mapping once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Martin R's link to find this solution:

```
let int = 11
print(chars.filter{$1 == int}.map{$0.0}[0]) // B
```

Comment: If you know that the value to key mapping in your dictionary (`chars`) is bijective (one to one), you could use `first` rather that `filter`: the former will allow for early exit upon first hit (short-circuiting), whereas the `filter` will pass the full un-ordered dictionary. E.g., `print(chars.first(where: { $1 == int })?.0 ?? "No such value")`.

Comment: Yes it is bijective. Thanks for this, it sped things up.

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of the fact that a Swift dictionary implements the `Collection` protocol, which extends the `Sequence` one, and use the `first` method which returns the first element of the sequence matching the given criteria:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func key(forValue value: Value) -> Key? {
        return first { $0.1 == value }?.0
    }
}

ints.key(forValue: "5")    // 5
ints.key(forValue: "99")   // nil
```

The above code works as a `Dictionary` can be assimilated to a sequence of `(Key, Value)` pairs. The only caveat is that in case of multiple keys matching to the same value we get only one of those keys, and it's not deterministic to say which one - although if your dictionary has a 1-on-1 mapping you don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to construct the 1:1 reverse lookup programatically:

```swift
    var chars = ["a":1,"b":2,"c":3]

    var ints = [Int:String]()
    for pair in chars { ints[pair.value] = pair.key }
```

`ints` contains:

```swift
    [1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c"]
```

Can be efficient if you're using it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Like @dfri mentioned, you can use the `first` method to get the first key for a given value:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {

    func key(for value: Value) -> Key? {
        return first(where: { $1 == value })?.key
    }


}
```

Comment: I already did add my solution to the [dupe target](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41386238/4573247), though... :) Also note that this does not, per se, get the "first" key, as dictionaries are non-ordered collections (so "first", semantically, holds no meaning here). It does get _some_ key, however, that may be the one single key with the supplied value, or just some among many keys that we first happened to stumble upon in the non-ordered collection.