# Invert keys for values in Swift dictionary, collecting duplicate values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
let dict = ["key1": "v1", "key2": "v1", "key3": "v2"]
```

I want to swap the values for keys so that the result to be:

```
result = ["v1": ["key1", "key2"], "v2": ["key3"]]
```

How can I do this without using `for` loops (i.e. in a functional way)?

Comment: Use a `for` loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping

Comment: Even if _you_ don't loop, _someone_ obviously has to loop, so what difference does it make? And "more elegantly" is a nebulous notion, not suited to Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @matt, no need to get pedantic on this question. You are aware that some people prefer their code cleaner and they call it "elegant". I don't think you didn't get what I wanted to say.

Comment: [Reverse Swift dictionary lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41383937)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use grouping initializer in Swift 4:

```
let dict = ["key1": "v1", "key2": "v1", "key3": "v2"]
let result = Dictionary(grouping: dict.keys.sorted(), by: { dict[$0]! })
```

Two notes:

1. You can remove `.sorted()` if the order of keys in resulting arrays is not important.
2. Force unwrap is safe in this case because we're getting an existing dictionary key as the `$0` parameter

Comment: Actually sorting is basically a NO-OP here, since a dictionary is unsorted.

Comment: @Cristik It is a collection of dictionary keys that is being sorted, not dictionary itself.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4, `Dictionary` has the [`init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892961-init) initializer that should serve well here.

```
let d = [1 : "one", 2 : "two", 3 : "three", 30: "three"]
let e = Dictionary(d.map({ ($1, [$0]) }), uniquingKeysWith: {
    (old, new) in old + new
})
```

If you did not have duplicate values in the original dict that needed to be combined, this would be even simpler (using [another new initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init)):

```
let d = [1 : "one", 2 : "two", 3 : "three"]
let e = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: d.map({ ($1, $0) }))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a special application of the commonly-needed ability to group key-value pairs by their keys.

```swift
public extension Dictionary {
  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Either `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`
  ///   or a `Sequence` with the same element type as that.
  /// - Returns: `[ KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value] ]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (key: Key, value: Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self =
      Dictionary<Key, [KeyValuePairs.Element]>(grouping: pairs, by: \.key)
      .mapValues { $0.map(\.value) }
  }

  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Like `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`,
  ///   but with unlabeled elements.
  /// - Returns: `[ KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value] ]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (Key, Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self.init( grouping: pairs.map { (key: $0, value: $1) } )
  }
}
```

With that, just flip each key-value pair and go to town.

```swift
Dictionary( grouping: dict.map { ($0.value, $0.key) } )
```