# Int in dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have dictionary :

```
var DictPl11 = [Int: String]()
```

I want to check for all integers, that are connected with one same string. For example with string "0":

```
DictPl11 = [1: "0", 4: "1", 3: "0", 6: "0"]
```

I want to print Int values 1, 3, 6

Thank you

Comment: Show us some of your codes. The steps and codes you've tried in PlayGround or in your project.

Comment: So you're looking for all the keys that have a particular value? (If so, dupe of [Swift dictionary get key for value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27218669/2976878))

Comment: I suggest you give `DictPl11` a better name. Swift's convention is to name variables with lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can try like this way.

```
var DictPl11 = [1: "0", 4: "1", 3: "0", 6: "0"]
var keyArray = DictPl11.flatMap { $1 == "0" ? $0 : nil } 
// [1, 3, 6] Keep in mind that this array doesn't have any order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try everything in PlayGround before asking, by the way.

You probably need to explicitly declare the type of your variable `DictPl11` as `[Int: String]`, as it crashed in my PlayGround.

By fast enumerating, you can get and print the `key` and `value` of your dictionary like so:

```
var DictPl11 = [1: "0", 4: "1", 3: "0", 6: "0"] as [Int: String]

for (key, value) in DictPl11 {
    print("key: \(key)")
    print("value: \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will keep it in my mind.