# Swift: Remove repeated Index and create a new dictionary with reversed index and value

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I have a dictionary with two Int’s A:B, and I want create a new dictionary that includes B as an index (with no repetition) and A as a value (only for repeated B’s):

```
var myDict : [Int:Int] = [12:2345, 14:2345, 99:1111, 67:1111, 77:7657, 132:3345, 199:6778]
```

Desired output:

```
var newDict: [Int:[Int]] = [2345: [ 12 , 14 ] , 1111: [ 99 , 67] ]
```

Note: the original dictionary contains over a thousand entries.

Comment: And what is your problem? Have you tried anything or do you expect us to write the code for you?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Someone will surely do. :p

Comment: Couldn't help it :/. I've been in situations myself where i have no idea how to approach things.

Comment: @Vollan A proper approach would be, come up with one solution at least and ask for an efficient one.

Comment: Check my updated answer now. I'm late to post the answer In searching for something short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through the first dict by enumerating it, that way you can switch the values in to the new dict

```
var newDict: [Int:[Int]] = [:]
let myDict : [Int:Int] = [12:2345, 14:2345, 99:1111, 67:1111, 77:7657, 132:3345, 199:6778]



     for values in myDict.enumerated() {
            var newValue = newDict[values.element.value] ?? []
            newValue.append(values.element.key)
            newDict[values.element.value] = newValue
        }

     newDict = newDict.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in
             value.count > 1
        }
```

Comment: Added a filter to fill your needs

Answer (score 1):

Here is the power of `swift`:

```
let newDict = Dictionary(grouping: myDict, by: {$0.value}).filter({$0.value.count > 1}).mapValues({$0.map({$0.key})})
print(newDict)
```

> **Output:** [1111: [67, 99], 2345: [12, 14]]

Comment: It's smooth with everything on 1 line, however, it decreases the readability :/

Comment: No! Its clear for who knows the uses of `grouping`, `map` and `filters`. If you read it carefully its clear how is it working.

Comment: I agree that it's clear using those methods, but using all in 1 line is not clear.

Comment: For that you can use two more variables containing the result of each filter. I just wanted to avoid the loop as OP mentioned  `Note: the original dictionary contains over a thousand entries.` Obviously this will be faster than two loops.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
var myDict: [Int:Int] = [12:2345, 14:2345, 99:1111, 67:1111, 77:7657, 132:3345, 199:6778]
let values = myDict.values
let tempValueSet = Set<Int>(values)
let uniqueValues = Array(tempValueSet)
var result = [Int: [Int]]()

for item in uniqueValues {
    result[item] = myDict.allKeys(forValue: item)
}
print(result)
```

And this is `Dictionary` extension:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func allKeys(forValue val: Value) -> [Key] {
        return self.filter { $1 == val }.map { $0.0 }
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
[6778: [199], 1111: [99, 67], 7657: [77], 3345: [132], 2345: [12, 14]]
```

For more reference about this extension : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27218964/2284065

If you don't want to use extension then you can use this code too :

```
var myDict: [Int:Int] = [12:2345, 14:2345, 99:1111, 67:1111, 77:7657, 132:3345, 199:6778]
let values = myDict.values
let tempValueSet = Set<Int>(values)
let uniqueValues = Array(tempValueSet)
var result = [Int: [Int]]()

for item in uniqueValues {
    result[item] = (myDict as NSDictionary).allKeys(for: item) as! [Int]
}
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes, the outcome is not what I wanted check Vollan filter. However thank you