# Swift dictionary: return values for all keys containing a prefix

Tags: swift, dictionary, search, key

I have a Dictionary (Swift 5)

`dict = ["ken" : 0, "Kendall" : 1, "kenny" : 2, "Sam" : 0, "Ben" : 3]`

I'm trying to build a search function that returns the values for all keys/names containing the prefix

so if the input is "ken" it should return the values for the keys/names "ken", "Kendall", and "Kenny" because they all contain "ken" in their first 3 characters.

`func search( string : String, dict : [String:Int] )->[Int] { }`

returns `[0,1,2]`

Comment: did you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41386238/13129471?

Comment: No I didn't but I think the solution might be included in there. Thank you

Comment: Please add your attempt at solving this.

Comment: I just added the solution. We should use a filter

Comment: One way is `dict.compactMap { $0.key.localizedStandardContains(string) ? $0.value : nil }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let dict = ["ken" : 0, "Kendall" : 1, "kenny" : 2, "Sam" : 0, "Ben" : 3]

let result = dict.filter( { $0.key.lowercased().hasPrefix("ken") } ).values
```