# Cannot invoke '<' with an argument list of type '(T, T)'

Tags: swift

I try to implement a function which will find index of minimal value in array:

```
func minIndex<T: Equatable>(array: [T]) -> Int {
    var minValue = array[0]
    var minIndex = Int()

    for (index, item) in enumerate(array) {
        if item < minValue as T {
            minValue = item
            minIndex = index
        }
    }
    return minIndex
}
```

But I have an error "Cannot invoke '<' with an argument list of type '(T, T)'" on line:

```
if item < minValue as T {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the elements to be `Comparable`, to that they can be compared with `<`:

```
func minIndex<T: Comparable>(array: [T]) -> Int {
    var minValue = array[0]
    var minIndex = Int()

    for (index, item) in enumerate(array) {
        if item < minValue {  // Your " as T" cast is not needed here
            minValue = item
            minIndex = index
        }
    }
    return minIndex
}
```

`Equatable` only means that they can be compared with `==`.

Comment: Thanks! And how about if I implement it in Array extension? With this changes:
    func minIndex<T: Comparable>() -> Int {
        var minValue = self[0]
...
        for (index, item) in enumerate(self) {
            if item < minValue {

I have the same error.

Comment: @AlesTsurko: You (currently) cannot define an extension method which can be applied only to a restricted Array type (e.g. require the elements to be Comparable). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value/24939100#24939100 for a similar issue.