# Filter function syntax?

Tags: swift

This works:

```
func removeObject<T : Equatable>(object: T, array: [T]) -> Array<T>
{
    return array.filter() { $0 != object }
}

let threeThings = ["one", "two", "three"]
twoThings = removeObject("three", threeThings)
```

However, I'd like to check for inequality with this `!==`. Then I get error "Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'"

How can this code be fixed? (I've see the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077090/8047) here but I'd like to learn how to use filter properly).

Comment: I've just written a Swift tutorial that could help you here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_type_constraints See the part that start with the sentence "A type constraint on a placeholder is often useful as a way of assuring the compiler that some message can be sent to an instance of the placeholder type."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *identical operator* `===` and its negation `!==` are only defined for
instances of classes, i.e. instances of `AnyObject`:

```
func removeObject<T : AnyObject>(object: T, array: [T]) -> Array<T>
{
    return array.filter() { $0 !== object }
}
```

`===` checks if two variables refer to the same single instance.

Note that your code

```
let threeThings = ["one", "two", "three"]
twoThings = removeObject("three", threeThings)
```

does still compile and run, but gives the (perhaps unexpected) result

```
[one, two, three]
```

The Swift strings (which are value types and not class types) are automatically
bridged to `NSString`, and the two instances of `NSString` representing "three"
need not be the same.

Comment: Thanks! In playgrounds I'm able to get the "perhaps unexpected" result only if I create the three some other way, like `"threeX".substringToIndex(5)`

Comment: @Yar: I tested it in a compiled project. Anyway, I only wanted to call attention to the fact that the Swift strings are bridged to NSString, so for strings your Equatable would be more appropriate. Filtering by `===` is suitable for instances of classes.

Comment: Agreed, this was more of a didactic exploration, but I learned quite a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `!==` instead of `!=`, then, instead of the type constraint `<T : Equatable>` say `<T : AnyObject>`. All you have to do is listen to what the error message is telling you!

Note that this has *nothing* to do with using the filter function. It is simply a matter of types. You cannot use a method with an object of a type for which that method is not implemented. `!==` is implemented for AnyObject so if you want to use it you must guarantee to the compiler that this type *will* be an AnyObject. That is what the type constraint does.

Comment: Thank you, and great point about it having nothing to do with `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

`!==` checks for "identity", not "equality". Identity is a property of reference types which all support the `AnyObject` protocol, and it means that the two variables that you are comparing point to the *same actual object*, and not just another object with the same value.

That means you can't use `===` or `!==` with normal value types, like strings, integers, arrays, etc.

Try typing this into a playground:

```
let a = "yes"
let b = a

println(a === b)
```

You should get a message saying that `String` doesn't conform to the `AnyObject` protocol, because String is a value type (a struct) and doesn't support `AnyObject`, so you can't use `===` with it.

You *can* use `===` with any instance of a class, because classes are reference types, not value types.

You could put a constraint on T requiring that it conform to `AnyObject`.

```
func removeObject<T : Equatable where T: AnyObject>...
```

It should work, then, for reference types (including all class instances). But then your function won't work for value types (which include all structs).

Why do you need to check for identity (`===`) instead of equality (`==`)?

Comment: Thanks, this is more of a comment than an answer, but I do appreciate the info!