# Referencing self in Dictionary extension

Tags: swift

I'm trying to extend Dictionary but can't reference self with a key. I'm confused as to why this is.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func foo() {
        var result = self["key"]
    }
}
```

I get this error :
Type 'DictionaryIndex' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

If anyone has any insight, it would be appreciated.

Comment: This does not compile because the dictionary key is a generic type and need not be a string. And you (currently) cannot define an extension method which is restricted to certain values of the generic placeholder,  compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value for the corresponding problem for Array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Dictionary` is a `Generic` struct. It is generic on its `Key` and `Value`. 
Thus in your extension you have to use `Key` as the type for the dictionary keys, and `Value` as the type for dictionary values.

The compiler is complaining because you are using the wrong type for the dictionary key extension.

Here is an example:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func ext(key: Key) {
        if let value = self[key] {
            // use your value
            println("Key is present")
        } else {
            println("No value for key")
        }
    }
}

let dic = ["A": 20]
dic.ext("A")
dic.ext("B")
```

Here is how you can do something similar ... it might make clearer why your test didn't work:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var foo: String? {
        if let key = "key" as? Key {
            return self[key] as? String
        }
        return nil
    }
}
let dic1 = ["A": "an A", "key": "the value"]
dic1.foo // "the value" as optional
dic.foo  // nil since dic value type is Int
```

Since `Dictionary` is a generic struct, you might reconsider extending it as if it is a specific *concrete* type.

Comment: Thank you very much! When you mention the concrete type, are you referring to an object or using a generic?

Comment: @MatthewChung ups ... _reconsider_ I meant _consider not to do so_. Extending a _generic_ type with logic specific to just one specific possible concrete type case, might introduce a lot of confusion in your code base. It is not difficult to define your specific dictionary of `[String : String]`. Just name a struct containing a `var` of type `[String : String]` and define the `subscript (key: String) -> String?` to just return or set the internal var. This way there will be no confusion in your code about a strange `Dictionary` extension that works just in case of `[String : String]`.

Comment: I like your point. I was however using this dictionary to serialize to json. Do you have a suggestion on a way to reduce the confusion while still allowing the object to serialize to json?

Comment: If you have a simple data model, just do your custom structs and json serialisation / deserialisation ... you know ... KISS principle ;-) In case of more complex data model, just look at the tones of solutions proposed from people smarter then me. [here](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios?utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_187&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly) you will find a few.