# Swift "where" Array Extensions

Tags: swift, where-clause, swift-extensions

As of Swift 2.0 it seems we can get closer to extensions of generic types applicable to predicated situations.

Although we still can't do this:

```
protocol Idable {
    var id : String { get }
}

extension Array where T : Idable {
    ...
}
```

...we can now do this:

```
extension Array {
    func filterWithId<T where T : Idable>(id : String) -> [T] {
    ...
    }
}
```

...and Swift grammatically accepts it. However, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to make the compiler happy when I fill in the contents of the example function. Suppose I were to be as explicit as possible:

```
extension Array {
    func filterWithId<T where T : Idable>(id : String) -> [T] {
        return self.filter { (item : T) -> Bool in
            return item.id == id
        }
    }
}
```

...the compiler will not accept the closure provided to filter, complaining

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((T) -> Bool)'

Similar if item is specified as Idable. Anyone had any luck here?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
extension Array {
    func filterWithId<T where T : Idable>(id : String) -> [T] {
    ...
    }
}
```

defines a generic method `filterWithId()` where the generic
placeholder `T` is restricted to be `Idable`. But that definition introduces a local placeholder `T`
which is completely unrelated to the array element type `T`
(and hides that in the scope of the method).

So you have *not* specified that the array elements must conform
to `Idable`, and that is the reason why you cannot call
 `self.filter() { ... }` with a closure which expects the elements
to be `Idable`.

As of Swift 2 / Xcode 7 beta 2, you can define extension methods on a generic type which are more restrictive on the template
(compare [Array extension to remove object by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value) for a very similar issue):

```
extension Array where Element : Idable {

    func filterWithId(id : String) -> [Element] {
        return self.filter { (item) -> Bool in
            return item.id == id
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a *protocol extension method*:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Idable {

    func filterWithId(id : String) -> [Generator.Element] {
        return self.filter { (item) -> Bool in
            return item.id == id
        }
    }
}
```

Then `filterWithId()` is available to all types conforming
to `SequenceType` (in particular to `Array`) if the sequence element
type conforms to `Idable`.

In **Swift 3** this would be

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : Idable {

    func filterWithId(id : String) -> [Iterator.Element] {
        return self.filter { (item) -> Bool in
            return item.id == id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with non-protocol types, like `extension Array where Iterator.Element : CGRect`?

Comment: @BenLeggiero: You can define an `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == CGRect { }`, i.e. for a protocol,  but the `Element` type of `Array` can only be restricted to a protocol. That might change in the future.