# Swift 4.1.2 Autocomplete: Suggesting extensions on Array that it shouldn't

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, swift-extensions, swift4.1

Maybe I'm going crazy here, but `extension Array where Element == String` in Swift 4.1.2 is exposing its properties in Swift's autocomplete on types when it should not be there.

For example, this extension:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    public var test: [String] {
        return ["test"]
    }
}
```

Then start typing:

`[123].te` ...

and Swift suggests that the `test` property is also available on [Int] which is impossible. Then the syntax checker pops up the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Is there something I'm missing? Perhaps some other/additional conformance restrictions that need to be used? Or is this a Swift bug?

[image]

Comment: This seems to happen in Swift 4.1 as well.

Comment: you can fix it extending the Collection instead of Array. `extension Collection where Element == String {`

Comment: This guy here says that `Element` can only be restricted by a protocol in an `Array` extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746190/swift-where-array-extensions#comment68188685_30746254

Comment: Note: in the bounty message I meant "link to a bug report ***if*** this is a bug."

Comment: It's a bug -- see my own accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug.

This Swift.org bug report demonstrates the same behavior:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5388