# Swift Generic constraints in init

Tags: swift, generics, init

I have generic and I want to be able to initialize it with specific constrains.  The constraints are only there for initialization.  The rest of the class doesn't care.  Here is a simplified example:

```
struct Generic<T> {
  let compare: (T, T) -> Bool
  init<T: Equatable>(data: [T]) {
    let handler: (T, T) -> Bool = { $0 == $1 }
    compare = handler
    insert(data)
  }

  init(compareHandler: (T, T) -> Bool, data[T]) {
    compare = self.compareHandler
    insert(data)
  }
}
```

You can see there's two initializers.  The second one obviously works fine.  However, in the first one the local type `T` is mismatched with the struct's generic Type.  So, for example, attempting to insert data I get `Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '([T])'`.  Is it possible for me to specialize the Struct's generic type only for the initialization or a specific function?

Note, I've already tried `init<T where T:Equatable>(data: [T])` to the same effect.

#### Update

I'm using the following workaround: I create a top level function and removing the specialized init:

```
func equatableHandler<T: Equatable>(left: T, right: T) -> Bool {
  return left == right
}
```

Clients of the struct can initialize using: `Generic(compareHandler: equatableHandler, data: data)`

It's not quite the "convenience" of using a specialized `init`, but I suppose it works well enough for my purposes.  I'm not a fan of creating top-level functions, but the generic is used so often for "Equatable" generics that it makes sense for me to define the handler once for clients to use.

Comment: I can't test it right now but this could work: `init<P: Equatable where T == P>(data: [P])`

Comment: It's a nice thought but it doesn't work either.  Despite the condition `T == P`, the compiler still believes they're not equal within the `init` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the first init method

```
init<T: Equatable>(data: [T])
```

introduces a local type placeholder `T` which hides (and is completely
unrelated to) the placeholder `T` of the `Generic` type, so it 
is essentially the same problem as in [Array extension to remove object by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value).

As of Swift 2 you can solve that with a "restricted extension":

```
extension Generic where T : Equatable {
    init(data: [T]) {
        let handler: (T, T) -> Bool = { $0 == $1 }
        compare = handler
        // ...
    }
}
```

For Swift 1.x the only solution is probably to define a global helper
function

```
func makeGeneric<T : Equatable>(data: [T]) -> Generic<T> {
    return Generic(compareHandler:  { $0 == $1 }, data: data)
}
```

(and I could not think of a sensible name for the function :).

Comment: This is an awesome use of the power of extensions in Swift 2!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is production code so I can't use Swift 2 yet.  While that looks like it would work in Swift 2, I can't verify it at the moment.

Comment: Yes, that does work.  It's similar to my workaround, except you've created a factory method whereas I simply provided a convenience handler.  Oddly, I did try doing that within the Struct using `static func` but I still ended up with type mismatches.  I'll mark your answer as accepted since I think there's no real way to do what I want except wait until Swift 2 arrives. :)