# Swift2: Array extension to remove object by value - Foundation

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have edited the question to focus on the last error. This is the last error in my code: an Array extension to remove object by value

It seems to be related to this post too:

[Array extension to remove object by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value)

But I am stuck :x

```
func cell(cell: FriendSearchTableViewCell, didSelectUnfollowUser user: PFUser) {
    if var followingUsers = followingUsers {
        ParseHelper.removeFollowRelationshipFromUser(PFUser.currentUser()!, toUser: user)
        // update local cache
        removeObject(user, fromArray: &followingUsers)
        self.followingUsers = followingUsers
    }
```

// for the 'removeObject' an error is raised:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'removeObject'

The function is calling the framework `Foundation` through a `Array+RemoveObject.swift`file which states:

```
import Foundation

// Thanks to Martin R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value

extension Array where Element : Equatable {
  // Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
mutating func removeObject(object : Generator.Element) {
        if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure my workspace is properly understanding that he needs to refer to this swift file to find the details of the identified `removeObject`.

Comment: Make sure to include all of the relevant code to *help others help you* -- right now the pieces that are causing you errors are not included in your code snippets. The error is saying that you cannot cast `PFQueryArrayResultBlock` to whatever `updateList` is. I can't find the definition for `updateList` anywhere in the included code so it's tough to help. The other error saying unresolved identifier `removeObject` is the same thing. Where is `removeObject` defined? The compiler can't find it and that's what's causing the error

Comment: You are totally right, and thank you for your comment. I looked for the 'updateList' and discovered that it was referring to AnyObject and not PFObject. I made the change and it solved the three errors!!!

I still have the last one. It refers to the framework "Foundation" where:

`import Foundation

extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
  // Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
  mutating func removeObject(object : Generator.Element) {
    if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
      self.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
  }
}`

Comment: A suggested version for Swift2 is: 

`extension Array {
 
    mutating func removeObject<T: Equatable>(object: T) -> Bool {
        var index: Int?
        for (idx, objectToCompare) in self.enumerate() {
            
            if let toCompare = objectToCompare as? T {
                if toCompare == object {
                    index = idx
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(index != nil) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index!)
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}`
But how to edit the code

Comment: @Jeremy  add it to the end of your array. Ex: followingUsers.removeObject(user)

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for your help. I have tried but now I get a new error based on the PFObject value:

`// update local cache
            followingUsers.removeObject(user)
            self.followingUsers = followingUsers`

Gives two errors

`Value of type '[PFUser]?' has no member 'removeObject'`and
`Assigning a property to itself`

Comment: Thats because PFUser does not conform to Equatable protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PFUser` does not conform to `Equatable` protocol so your extension doesn't apply. But a `PFUser` is identified through its user name. You can solve your problem with `filter`, no extension required:

```
func cell(cell: FriendSearchTableViewCell, didSelectUnfollowUser user: PFUser) {
    if var followers = followingUsers {
        ParseHelper.removeFollowRelationshipFromUser(PFUser.currentUser()!, toUser: user)
        // update local cache
        followers = followers.filter { $0.username != user.username } 
        self.followingUsers = followers
    }
}
```