# How to remove single object in array from multiple matching object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
var testarray = NSArray() 
testarray = [1,2,2,3,4,5,3] 
print(testarray) 
testarray.removeObject(2)
```

I want to remove single object from multiple matching object like

```
myArray = [1,2,2,3,4,3]
```

When I remove

```
myArray.removeObject(2)
```

then both objects are deleted. I want remove only single object.

I tried to use many extension but no one is working properly. I have already used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 2**

Solution when using a simple Swift array:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3]

if let index = myArray.indexOf(2) {
    myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

It works because `.indexOf` only returns the **first occurence** of the found object, as an Optional (it will be `nil` if object not found).

It works a bit differently if you're using NSMutableArray:

```
let nsarr = NSMutableArray(array: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3])
let index = nsarr.indexOfObject(2)
if index < Int.max {
    nsarr.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
}
```

Here `.indexOfObject` will return `Int.max` when failing to find an object at this index, so we check for this specific error before removing the object.

**Swift 3**

The syntax has changed but the idea is the same.

*Array:*

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3]
if let index = myArray.index(of: 2) {
    myArray.remove(at: index)
}
myArray // [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
```

*NSMutableArray:*

```
let myArray = NSMutableArray(array: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3])
let index = myArray.index(of: 2)
if index < Int.max {
    myArray.removeObject(at: index)
}
myArray // [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
```

In Swift 3 we call `index(of:)` on both Array and NSMutableArray, but they still behave differently for different collection types, like `indexOf` and `indexOfObject` did in Swift 2.

Comment: Eric, i am using mutable array in my project so, generate this type of error, Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'indexOf'

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5: getting index of the first occurrence

```
if let i = yourArray.firstIndex(of: yourObject) {
   yourArray.remove(at: i)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove all duplicate objects then you can use below code.

```
    var testarray = NSArray()
    testarray = [1,2,2,3,4,5,3]

    let set = NSSet(array: testarray as [AnyObject])
    print(set.allObjects)
```

Comment: Off-topic. OP said `I want to remove single object`.

Comment: "I want to remove single object from multiple matching object like" value 3 is also 2 times!

Comment: You don't understand. :) OP doesn't asks to remove duplicate objects. He asks to remove only one of the duplicates.

Comment: Then question should be how to remove object from index 2 from array [1,2,2,3,4,5,3]