# Can't form Range with end < start

Tags: ios, swift, loops, for-loop, swift2

While I try to create a `for in` loop, it gives me an error stating "cant form Range with end < start". Value of i comes 4362626962. How can I fix it?

```
    for i in 1...slashList.count{
        let index = slashList[i]

        if !quotaList.contains(index+1)
        {
        slashList.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: just do not make your slashList < 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for has two problems:

1. If `slashList.count` is 0 (because `slashList` is empty), it would try to count from 1 to 0 adding 1 (which results in an infinite loop), that's why the compiler gives you the error `start > end`.
2. if `slashList.count` is greater than 0 (`slashList` is not empty), it would use an index which is out of bounds, because you count from 1 to `slashList.count`, while the indexes go from 0 to `slashList.count - 1`

to check all indexes it should be:

```
for i in 0 ..< slashList.count { 
   // your code 
}
```

to ignore the first element (index 0) do:

```
for i in 1 ..< slashList.count {
   // your code 
}
```

for your special case, it would seem better to me to do something like:

```
for element in slashList {    
    if !quotaList.contains(element+1)
    {
        slashList.removeObject(element)
    }
}
```

You can use removeObject from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30724543/386738). If, for some reason, you also need the index, do:

```
for (index, element) in slashList.enumerate() {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with, it should be 0.. not 1...

```
for i in 0..slashList.count{
    let index = slashList[i]

    if !quotaList.contains(index)
    {
    slashList.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you start loop from index 1 instead 0? If you really need this, you must check if `slashList` empty array:

```
if !slashList.isEmpty {
    // your code here
}
```

Also removing items from array you numerating is bad practice. Assume that you want to loop from 0, then there is swifty way to get what you want:

```
slashList = slashList.enumerate().flatMap{quotaList.contains($0.index + 1) ? $0.element : nil}
```