# Understanding Equatable in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I have an array of enum which I need to delete one of the Enum. I have written generic remove operation based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value). We usually conform Equatable to Struct. So I am curious how Equatable will behave in Enum. If It is not a right way to write generic remove operation for collection of Enum array, then what will be the right one?

```
enum APIEndPoints: Equatable {
   case image
   case email
   case others
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By definition, two enums of the same type are equal if they are of the same case. Thus `.image` is equal to `.image`, for example. That is why you are able to test enum instances against one another using the `==` operator to find out what case something is. Indeed, this fact is sort of the *point* of enums.

(This, by the way, is also why enums cannot have stored properties. Two `.image` instances with different stored values for the same property would *not* be equal. And that would completely defeat the purpose of enums.)