# Cannot convert return expression of type Int to Int

Tags: swift

I wonder why this is not work:

```
func removingOnce (_ item: Int, from array:[Int]) -> [Int]{


var intToReturn :Int?
intToReturn = 0

for ob in array5{

    if (ob == item){
     intToReturn = item
    }
}

return intToReturn
}
```

It warn me with error: Cannot convert an expression of type Int to return type Int.

It make no sense at all

Comment: `-> [Int]` doesn't it mean that the return should be an array of `Int` ?

Comment: your return type is Array of Int but u returning Int

Comment: You mean square brackets show that i want to return an array of int objects?

Comment: Why don't you post the *real* error message? – (And why do you call the function "removingOnce" if it does not remove anything?)

Comment: Is this your real code?  There is no `array5` passed in or declared in your function.

Comment: @MartinR sorry, i didnt mention that those brackets are important. It suppose to take an array, remove a value from it and return modified array.

Comment: It is always a good idea state what you are trying to do, and to copy/paste the error messages, in order to avoid misunderstandings :) – Have a look at [Array extension to remove object by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value) for various solutions to remove an item from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning reads

> Cannot convert an expression of type Int to return type [Int]

and not as you stated it.  (I tested it in Playground)

The reason for your error is that you return an Int value `intToReturn`, but according to the method definition, it should return an array of Ints `->[Int]`

Either change the return value to the resulting Int array or change the return type in the method definition to `->Int?`

Also, you declare `intToReturn` as an optional Int value.  `(Int?)` but just after that, you assign it a value and it will not ever be nil.  Rather do:

```
var intToReturn:Int  = 0 or 
var intToReturn = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**[]** menas array

```
func removingOnce (_ item: Int, from array:[Int]) -> Int{


var intToReturn :Int?
intToReturn = 0

for ob in array5{

    if (ob == item){
     intToReturn = item
    }
}

return intToReturn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution in my opinion to do this method:

```
func removingOnce (_ item: Int, from array:[Int]) -> Int? {
    for ob in array {
        if (ob == item){
            return ob
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The problem was the returning value. You wanted to return Int and in function you return an array of Ints.