# How to remove element from array in Swift based on value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following code:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker){
let lat: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.latitude
let lng: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.longitude
var formattedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,longitude: lng)
markersArray.remove(formattedCoordinate)
self.clean()
}

func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker){
let lat: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.latitude
let lng: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.longitude
var formattedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,longitude: lng)
markersArray.remove(formattedCoordinate)
}
```

As you can see I am trying to "remove" the "formattedCoordinate" from markersArray. I saw that there are options like .filter and other methods which enables removing an element at a specific index, but here I would like to remove that specific coordinate from the array. How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array extension to remove object by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value)

Comment: I tried those, didn't work

Comment: How is `markersArray` defined, what does it contain? What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>. It contains lat and long coordinates. I would like to remove one of those when a 'marker' was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

```
    markers = markers.filter({ (coordinateToRemove) -> Bool in
        return coordinateToRemove.latitude == formattedCoordinate.latitude && coordinateToRemove.longitude == formattedCoordinate.longitude
    })
```

I had the same problem solved it by rounding off the values of **latitude and longitude**(as they can be different by some decimal in **formattedCoordinate** Object) that you are comparing using

round(coordinateToRemove.latitude)

and comparing them separately.

Comment: Round off by how many digits? I don't want to lose precision.