# generic parameter could not be inferred swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have write an Array extension for distinct items

```
extension Array {
    func distinct<T: Equatable>() -> [T]{
        var unique = [T]()
        for i in self{
            if let item = i as? T {
                if !unique.contains(item){
                    unique.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        return unique
    }
}
```

And try to call this function like below

```
let words = ["pen", "Book", "pencile", "paper", "Pin", "Colour Pencile", "Marker"]
words.distinct()
```

But it give error "generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred swift"

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091046/unable-to-use-contains-within-a-swift-array-extension ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get rid of this error by telling the compiler what you expecting:

```
let a: [String] = words.distinct()
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know what the generic T is.
Much better solution would be tell the compiler that you define distinct function to all of the arrays where their Element is Equatable:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func distinct() -> [Element]{
        var unique = [Element]()
        for i in self{
            if let item = i as? Element {
                if !unique.contains(item){
                    unique.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        return unique
    }
}
```